# How to installGestures on Reality Composer

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

is there a way to add `installGestures` in reality composer?

i am able to do it in code, but i don`t want to mix too much code and ui parts. so i am searching how i can do the drag and drop part in reality composer.

here is the code snipit to do it in code and what i did so far.

```swift
arView.installGestures([.translation], for: modelEntity)
```

does anyone know how to enable this in reality composer?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reality Composer 1.5 allows you implicitly implement gestures only for animated behaviors. At the moment there's no explicit way to turn on `Translation`, `Rotation` or `Pinch` gestures in Reality Composer. Only via RealityKit, as you indicated.

```
arView.installGestures([.all], for: entity)
```

P. S.

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418011/is-there-a-way-to-let-an-entitytranslationgesturerecognizer-recognize-touches-on/75419095#75419095) will show you how raycasting works in conjunction with RealityKit gestures.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with your hin now like this:

```swift
let startScene = try! RCProjectFile.loadStartScene()
if let cube = startScene.cube {
    if let cube = cube as? Entity & HasCollision {
        cube.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        arView.installGestures(for: cube)
    }
}
```

Comment: But your question was about Reality Composer, wasn't it? ))))

Comment: yes, i combined both, so i create everything in reality composer and load the scene and make the one object dragable in code. but now i have the issue, that i have muliple scenes that have dragable objects, but i cannot access these scenes from code because they are loaded from another scene. any ideas @andy-fedoroff? Thanks