# Is there a way to let an EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer recognize touches on the entity when another entity is in front of it?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

In RealityKit there is the default `EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer` which you can install to Entities to allow dragging them along their anchoring plane. In my use-case, I will only allow moving one selected entity at a time. As such, I would like to enable the user to drag the selected entity even while it is behind another entity from the POV of the camera.

I have tried setting a delegate to the `EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer` and implementing the function `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool`, but the gesture recognizer still does not receive the touch when another entity is in front.

My assumption is that behind the scenes it is doing a HitTest, and possibly only considering the first Entity that is hit. I'm not sure if that is correct though. Were that the case, ideally there would be some way to set a CollisionMask or something on the hit test that the translation gesture is doing, but I have not found anything of the sort.

Do I just need to re-implement the entire behavior myself with a normal `UIPanGestureRecognizer` ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

### Hypersimple solution

The easiest way to control a model with RealityKit's transform gestures, even if it's occluded by another model, is to assign a collision shape only for the controlled model.

```
modelOne.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)

arView.installGestures(.translation, for: modelOne as! (Entity & HasCollision))
```

### Advanced solution

However, if both models have collision shapes, the solution should be as follows. This example implements  `EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer`, `TapGesture`, `CollisionCastHit` collection, `EntityScaleGestureRecognizer` and collision masks.

Click to play GIF's animation.

[image]

I've implemented SwiftUI 2D tap gesture to deactivate cube's collision shape in a special way. `TapGesture()` calls the raycasting method, which fires a 3D ray from the center of the screen. If the ray does not hit any model with a required collision mask, then `"Raycasted"` string does not appear on the screen, therefore you will not be able to use the RealityKit's drag gesture for model translation.

```
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI
import ARKit
import PlaygroundSupport     // iPadOS Swift Playgrounds app version
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @State var mask1 = CollisionGroup(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    @State var mask2 = CollisionGroup(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ARContainer(arView: $arView, mask1: $mask1, mask2: $mask2)
                .gesture(
                    TapGesture().onEnded { raycasting() }
                )
            Text(text).font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
    func raycasting() {            
        let ray = arView.ray(through: arView.center)           
        let castHits = arView.scene.raycast(origin: ray?.origin ?? [], 
                                         direction: ray?.direction ?? [])

        for result in castHits {
            if (result.entity as! Entity & HasCollision)
                                            .collision?.filter.mask == mask1 {
                text = "Raycasted"
            } else {
                (result.entity as! ModelEntity).model?.materials[0] = 
                           UnlitMaterial(color: .green.withAlphaComponent(0.7))
                (result.entity as! Entity & HasCollision).collision = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ARContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    @Binding var mask1: CollisionGroup
    @Binding var mask2: CollisionGroup
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.cameraMode = .ar
        arView.renderOptions = [.disablePersonOcclusion, .disableDepthOfField]
        
        let model1 = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.2))
        model1.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        model1.collision?.filter.mask = mask1
        
        let model2 = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.2), 
                            materials: [UnlitMaterial(color: .green)])
        model2.position.z = 0.4
        model2.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        model2.collision?.filter.mask = mask2
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0,0,-1])
        anchor.addChild(model1)
        anchor.addChild(model2)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        arView.installGestures(.translation, 
                                for: model1 as! (Entity & HasCollision))
        arView.installGestures(.scale, 
                                for: model2 as! (Entity & HasCollision))
        return arView
    }   
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

---

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, neither of these approaches will work for me as I need to retain the active collision component to enable other behaviors (physics, receiving taps on the other models via raycasting, etc). 

Shame that they don't allow us to set a collision filter for the gestures. 

Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 0):

Could you have the entity which is “behind” part of a specific collision group, and then use the raycast with that collision group?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/scene/raycast(origin:direction:length:query:mask:relativeto:)

Comment: I was thinking... you could even make your own EntityGestureRecognizer implementation that worked only for the entity you want (the one behind)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entitygesturerecognizer

Comment: These are too many "could" and "?" in what should be an answer according to [answer]. Please [edit] to add the info from the comment to the answer post itself and to get closer to [answer]. You did mean to provide a solution, didn't you? If you are not sure whether it is the solution please phrase an explained conditional answer, like "If your problem is ... then the solution is ... because ... .".

Comment: I wanted to leave a comment but I cannot without certain reputation, so not sure what I am supposed to do?

I believe that my suggestion is a possible answer for the poster to be clear.

Comment: You are aware of the need for the commenting privilege, which you do not have, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation pleaes do not decide to misuse a different mechanism, an answer post, for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed to do. Please answer as an answer, not as a question. If you cannot turn this into a (conditional) answer please delete it and find a question you can clearly answer with guessing or needing info first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).